# WSO2 IS SAML2.0 Deactivates user after single login

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I downloaded WSO2 IS, took care of all the prerequisites and started it using "wso2server.bat --run" command.

It's running and I am able to configure it in Management Console as Identity Provider (SAML 2.0). I also added my app as Service Provider (SAML 2.0). SSO seems to be working - I navigate to my app, it redirects to WSO2 IS where I log in using default admin/admin. I am then redirected to assertion service in my app when I am authenticating a user. Everything great so far!

The problem is that when I close the browser (using incognito mode) and try to repeat that process and login to WSO2 IS using the same user (admin/admin) I get error message:

**"Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again."**

I also get similar message in console:

**[2018-02-08 15:57:39,258] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.listener.SCIMUserOperationListener} -  Trying to login from an inactive account of user: admin**

How is that possible? It looks like the second I use given user during SSO process - that account gets deactivated. I can't even login to WSO2 IS Management Console.

I did not change any configuration other than mentioned above.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Change log level to debug from management console and replicate the scenario. Then chek the logs to get what is happening.

Comment: What is the Identity Server version that you are using ?